# Sending a command to screen via PHP?

Tags: php, command

I was wondering how I could execute a command through PHP into a screen running on my virtual private server.

i.e.

```
if(submit){
do "say This is a minecraft server." in screen.
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please help. I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "screen"? The console? A web page? Some Minecraft thing? How and when are you running the script?

Comment: I mean the console. screen -r, um.. Yeah. Running in Terminal.

I haven't got a PHP script for it, I was just wondering how I could do this.

Answer (score 0):

Still unclear on exactly what you mean, but if this is what you're looking for, you can execute linux commands by using the backtick operator, such as

```
echo `ls`;
```

to print the contents of the directory where the script is located. So if you wanted to print commands to your server, you could do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script under screen, then just `echo` or `print` the data you want to display.

Otherwise you can:

- make a system call to [write](http://linux.die.net/man/1/write) or [wall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall)
- write to a file that you are `tail -f`ing in the screen (or some other system by which the screen polls something for new messages)
- run a service in the screen that you can connect to over the network